# Mock url to make a call to in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have a method that takes a URL as a param, makes a request to it using HttpClient and if the `content-type` starts with `image`, then returns true, otherwise false. I'm now trying to write a test for it. How do I go about creating a mock/fake URL that the call can be made to?

Comment: Mock/fake HttpClient instead

Comment: @Fabio Of course! Why didn't I think of that. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share with us the (to be tested) method?

Comment: I ended up following this https://dev.to/gautemeekolsen/how-to-test-httpclient-with-moq-in-c-2ldp

Answer (score 0):

There is a very lightweight library [Flurl](https://flurl.dev/docs/fluent-http/) which is actually a wrapper around the HttpClient. It has built in support for UnitTesting.

Comment: It does not seem it is actively maintained. It has 50+ open issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should not mock/fake the URL, you should mock HttpClient.

You can create an interface (IHttpClient) for HttpClient which contain all methods from HttpClient or all methods you need for you development. Then you can create a simple wrapper which will extend the HttpClient and implement IHttpClient interface.

However, such approach is a bit tricky. So, maybe you should have a look to some libraries, for example [Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit). But in this case you need some work to restructure your requests system.